# Min Max Normalization/Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, normalization, pca, structural-equation-model

I have a dataset with county level data where N=3119 with 93 variables. I am trying to do a PCA, EFA and or CFA. The data has been given to me already min/max normalized, ranging from (0,1). Theory states that the data should be normally distributed for CFA/SEM, but my understanding is that min/max normalization does not change the distribution of the data, only it's scale.

It is clear to me that I do not have multivariate normality or univariate normality due to the skewness of data. I guess what's confusing me, is when people seemingly throw around the term normalization interchangeably with the meaning of normal distribution.

So can I go forward with my analysis since min/max normalization has been performed, or do I need to look more towards other log/box cox transformations to adjust the distribution prior to running my analysis? Is it okay to log transform data that has already been min/max normalized?

Comment: Or does this the normality assumption mean the the residuals of the CFA need to be normal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/statistics/info) page of the Statistics tag for usage guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> my understanding is that min/max normalization does not change the distribution of the data, only it's scale.

Correct.  If you print a `hist()`ogram of original and transformed data, they should look identical.  Only the x-axis scale will change.

> the term normalization interchangeably with the meaning of normal distribution

Indeed, these are completely separate issues.

> Is it okay to log transform data that has already been min/max normalized?

Taking the `log()` would affect 0--1 data differently than data further up the real-number line.  But I don't see why you need to transform the data when nonnormality corrections are available for *SE*s (in EFA or CFA) and model-fit test statistics (relevant for CFA).  Independent-components analysis might be an alternative to PCA if your data are not normal.